# Compare Mongo DB array elements to itself to find array inside a document with distinct values in a particular field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, compare, aggregate

I have a mongo collection QT_STG as below:

```
Document #1
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603f82844cc37e190862e0e6"),
    "saleid"   : "M5111161000",
    "parentID" : "1",
    "distid"   : "123",
    "gracePeriod" : "12"
    "lineDetails" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "endDate" : "3/26/2022"
        },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "endDate" : "3/26/2022"
        },


     ]
}
Document #2
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("603f82844cc37e190862e0e6"),
    "saleid"   : "M5111161000",
    "parentID" : "1",
    "distid"   : "123",
    "gracePeriod" : "12"
    "lineDetails" : [ 
        {
            "id" : "1",
            "endDate" : "3/24/2022"
       },
        {
            "id" : "2",
            "endDate" : "3/22/2022"
        },
        {
            "id" : "3",
            "endDate" : "4/22/2022"
        }
     ]
}
```

I should be able to select documents with linedetails size more than '2' and with distinct 'endDate' in 'lineDetails' array.

In the above sample , only Document#2 has to get selected. Can someone help me here.

Answer (score 0):

first you shoud add new fileds that contains size of `lineDetails`
and then match all doc that `numLineDetails` is morethan 2 then `unwind`
the group by _id and use `addToSet` to remove duplication
and then project the array

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[
  {
    '$addFields': {
      'numLineDetails': {
        '$size': '$lineDetails'
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$match': {
      'numLineDetails': {
        '$gt': 2
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$lineDetails'
    }
  }, {
    '$group': {
      '_id': {
        'id': '$_id'
      }, 
      'arr': {
        '$addToSet': {endDate:'$$ROOT.lineDetails.endDate',id:'$$ROOT.lineDetails.id'}
      }
    }
  }, {
    '$project': {
      'arr': 1, 
      '_id': 0
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick help. The solution is close to my need but not exactly what I expect. I do not want to remove duplicates but want to consider arrays that have only distinct values in it and skip documents which have duplicated end date in the array.

Comment: could you provide sample expected data

Comment: In the sample given in problem statement, Document# 2 has to be returned as it has all objects in the linedetails array has differnt enddate.

Answer (score 0):

Added few more conditions to @Mohammad Naimi solution and got the result.

```
 db.quoting_staging.aggregate(
    [
      {
        "$addFields": {
          "numLineDetails": {
            "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$lineDetails", [] ] }
          }
        }
      }
    , {
        '$match': {
          'numLineDetails': {
            '$gt': 2
          }
        }
      },
      {
        '$unwind': {
          'path': '$lineDetails'
        }
      }, 
      {
        '$group': {
          '_id': {
            'id': '$_id'
          }, 
          'sid': { "$first": "$$ROOT.sid" },
          'arr': {
            '$addToSet': '$$ROOT.lineDetails.endDate'
          },
          'initialArrSize':{ "$first": "$$ROOT.numLineDetails" }
        }
      },
        {
        "$addFields": {
          "distinctArrSize": {
            "$size": { "$ifNull": [ "$arr", [] ] }
          }
        }
      },
      {
        '$project': {
          'arr': 1, 
          '_id': 1,
          'sid': 1,
          'distinctArrSize':1,
          'initialArrSize':1
        }
      }
      , {
        '$match': {$expr: {$eq: ["$distinctArrSize", "$initialArrSize"]}}
      }
    ])
```

Comparing initial 'linedetails' size 'arr' size helped me to identify document with  unique enddates in its linedetails.